# How to overwrite ftdetect from a plugin loaded with lazy?

Tags: neovim, ftdetect, plugin-lazy

I am using [ansible.vim](https://github.com/pearofducks/ansible-vim/blob/master/ftdetect/ansible.vim#L36)  I am  loading it with lazy:

```
return {
 'pearofducks/ansible-vim',
}
```

and this is the configuration I have for `ansiblels`:

```lua
      ["ansiblels"] = function()
                lspconfig.ansiblels.setup({
                    filetypes = {
                        "ansible",
                        "yaml.ansible",
                        "yaml.ansible_hosts"
                    },
                    settings = {
                        ansible = {
                            validation = {
                                lint = {
                                    arguments = "-c ~/.config/ansible-lint.yml"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
            end
```

The plugin `ftdetect`  https://github.com/pearofducks/ansible-vim/blob/master/ftdetect/ansible.vim#L34-L36 creates this group:

```
augroup ansible_vim_ftyaml_ansible
  au!
  au BufNewFile,BufRead * if s:isAnsible() | set ft=yaml.ansible | en
augroup END
```

But I would like to use `ft=ansible` instead of `ft=yaml.ansible` (so that I can get all the syntax highlights if using yaml.ansible, I lose all the jinga2file type)

I tried this:

```lua
    vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd({
        "BufRead",
        "BufNewFile"
    }, {
        pattern = {
            "*/ansible/*.yml",
            "*/tasks/*.yml"
        },
        callback = function()
            vim.bo.filetype = "ansible"
        end
    })
```

But for an unknown reason, I still get the filetype `yaml.ansible` instead of only `ansible`

How could I modify the group to be instead:

```
augroup ansible_vim_ftyaml_ansible
  au!
  au BufNewFile,BufRead * if s:isAnsible() | set ft=ansible | en
augroup END
```

But without altering the plugin, is there a way to overwrite this?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by loading my custom options after the plugin, the order of loading the plugins and custom options matters, I changed my `init.lua` from:

```lua
require("user.options")
require("user.keymaps")
require("user.lsp-diagnostic")
require("user.lazy")
```

to:

```lua
-- order matters
require("user.keymaps")
require("user.lsp-diagnostic")
require("user.lazy")
require("user.options")
```